# Adding/Editing master-children entities in a single Windows forms

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, user-interface, winforms

How would you go about designing a windows form that allows adding/editing a master entity along with it's child entities? For example When adding/editing an Order, Order-Items would also need to be added/edited on the same Windows form.

Answer (score 0):

Either with a datagrid, embedded repeater usercontrol, or with a dialog.

You could have a list control, that when selected, displays the view/edit control in a different frame.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.3eed28a035.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.3eed28a035.png)